# How can I split a pipe-separated string into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have this string:

```
var(HELLO,)|var(Hello again)| var(HOW ARE YOU?)|outV(0)|outV(1)|outV(2)|END
```

I want to split it on the `|`. I don't want it to split at the white space, only at the `|`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14):

The way to do this is clearly documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=split#string.split).

Example:

```
>>> myString = "subString1|substring2|subString3"
>>> myString = myString.split("|")
>>> print myString
["subString1", "subString2", "subString3"]
```